# How to get the the source data of all the series of a chart in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, charts

```
With ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1)
INSPECT_CHARTS_NUMBER = .ChartObjects.Count
For c= 1 To .ChartObjects.Count
Set INSPECT_CHART = .ChartObjects(c).Duplicate

.ChartObjects(c).Chart.SetSourceData Source:=.Range("e4:h4")

Next lngC
End With
```

I do the above to change the source data of a chart in VBA this line `.Chart.SetSourceData Source:=.Range("e4:h4")`does do job, but this will not work if there are multiple series in that chart.

How can I get the sourcedata of all the series and then how can I change them separately?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an example

Let's say the series collection of the active chart is picking the values from `A1:A5` and `C1:C5`. So the below code will change the source to `A8:A12` and `C8:C12`

```
Dim sc As SeriesCollection
Dim i as Long, j as Long

j = 1

For i = 1 To ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.Count
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(i).Values = "=Sheet1!R8C" & j & ":R12C" & j
    j = j + 2 '<~~ Adding 2 for Col C
Next
```

**Screenshot**

Before

[image]

After

[image]

Comment: Nice one @Sid. I'm on my phone ;)

Answer (score 3):

Use `.seriescollection`

```
Set ChartSeries = ChartObj.Chart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries

With ChartSeries
    .Name = "Chart Series 1"
    .Values = Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
    .XValues = Array("alpha", "beta", "gamma", "delta", "epsilon")
End With
```

More on this [link](http://www.databison.com/index.php/vba-chart/).

Comment: + 1 :) `I'm on my phone ;) – glh 2 mins ago` Formatted the post for you :)

Answer (score 3):

You can access the data source of the chart series by retrieving the series **.Formula** string.

After that you can change the Formula (with Replace for example) and then reapply the Formula for the series.

Code example (provided for the solution from Sid):

```
Dim chart As ChartObject

For Each chart In ActiveSheet.ChartObjects

    Dim ser As Series

    For Each ser In chart.Chart.SeriesCollection
        Dim oF As String
        Dim nF As String
        oF = ser.Formula
        nF = Replace(oF, "$1", "$8") ' Changing the row 1 to row 8
        nF = Replace(nF, "$5", "$12") ' Changing the row 5 to row 12
        ser.Formula = nF
    Next ser

Next chart
```

Be sure to use the **$** sign, because the series **.Formula** uses numbers for the chart **Type** representation. The sign helps to omit replacing the chart Type in the formula.

Hope this helps...