# How to change the sourcedata for a particular series in an chart in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I need to change the sourcedata of a particular series of an chart in VBA. I saw the code used in this: [How to get the the source data of all the series of a chart in VBA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16100955/how-to-get-the-the-source-data-of-all-the-series-of-a-chart-in-vba) and my code looks like this:

```
For Each objChrt In ActiveSheet.ChartObjects
        Set myChart = objChrt.Chart
        myFileName = "myChart" & Index
Next
```

But I am not sure how to change this code:

```
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(i).Values = "=Sheet1!R8C" & j & ":R12C" & j
```

By the way, I am using Excel 2003. Need some guidance on how to do this.

Comment: Is there only one chart on the sheet? What's the actual source of the data?

Comment: There are more than one chart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
myChart.SeriesCollection(1).Values = "Sheet1!R2C1:R7C1" ' refers to A2:A7
```

Above will work provided you already have an existing chart with existing series.
If not, you need to set the source data instead like this:

```
myChart.SetSourceData Source:=Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A7")
```

Comment: I have more than one chart.

Comment: @lakesh Yeah, you will add that within the loop after you `Set myChart = objChrt.Chart`. Now, if you're source data and or series comes from different ranges as well then, you'll have to work on dynamically changing that as well.

Comment: how to change the x-axis of a chart?

Comment: @lakesh Use `XValues` property. Like this: `myChart.SeriesCollection(1).XValues  = "Sheet1!R2C2:R7C2"`

Comment: The XValues are for all graphs. Do I still change myChart.SeriesCollection(1).XValues?

Comment: @lakesh Technically, each series collection have its own `XValues` although changing just 1 looks like it applies to all (visually on the graph). But if you check on the chart and analyze `Select Data` you'll see that each series have it's own `XValues`.

Comment: One more question, "Sheet1!R2C1:R7C1" ' refers to A2:A7 => How does this mapping work? can explain?

Comment: @lakesh Actually that refers to `$A$2:$A$7` (A1 Notation) with absolute reference. In R1C1 notation, it is `R2(row 2) C1(column 1) : R7 (row 7) C1 (column 1)`.

Comment: One more question: When I write this: myChart.SeriesCollection(1).XValues = Sheets("Sheet2").Range(Cells(4, 1), Cells(rowNum - 2, 1)), it gives me a error saying application-defined or object-defined error. How do I solve this?

Comment: @lakesh You need to pass it as *String* not as *Object* as seen in your example and mine. So pass the string address instead using `Address Property` Something like this: `Sheets("Sheet2").Range(Cells(4, 1), Cells(rowNum - 2, 1)).Address(External:=True)`. Setting *External Argument* to `True` includes the `Sheet` in the address and thus avoid unexpected results.